# Accordion Force Open Tab

Tags: php, jquery

I have an accordian on my php script with 4 tabs.  I want to add a conditional clause to determine which one is open to begin.  Currrently, none of them start out open.

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/9cqo3s73/3/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate a `click` in the tab you want open at the begining. Like this:

```
$('.accordion-section-title:eq(0)').click(); // Can be eq(0), eq(1) or eq(2)
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/9cqo3s73/4/

Comment: It didn't work, but I think it might be due to the structure.  Here's a look at how it works:     `code`    <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Overview</a>
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Onsite Activty</a>
`code`

Comment: Please add the outputted HTML to the question or prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) show it working.

Comment: Check: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/9cqo3s73/4/. Note that you need only one `ready`.